# Cannot find appropriate Makefile processor on this system

Tags: compiling, cpu, cmake

Im trying to install cmake in my computer with an AMD A8 5600K and a GTX nvidia 1060, but in the process this error appears:

> CMake 3.7.2, Copyright 2000-2016 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors Found
>   GNU toolchain C compiler on this system is: gcc C++ compiler on this
>   system is: g++ --------------------------------------------- 
>   Error when bootstrapping CMake: Cannot find appropriate Makefile processor on this system.
>   Please specify one using environment variable MAKE.

I dont know what it means, my CPU isnt compatible with cmake or what? i have a clean install of ubuntu only with gcc and g++ installed.

Comment: Are you trying to install `cmake` ... from *source*? if so, *why*?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `make`. Do:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```